# Can not mix aggregate and non aggregate in If Function

Tags: if-statement, aggregate-functions

I have a calculated Filed called **Gross Margin**: SUM([Gross Profit])/SUM([Billed Revenue])

I want to create another for **Current Year Gross Margin** using this formula but it does not work:

```
IF YEAR([Date (Years)])= [Year] AND QUARTER([Date (Quarters)]) = [Quarter] THEN [Gross Margin] END
```

It states it cannot mix aggregate and non aggregate together. How can I solve this please?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: I am attempting to do this in Tableau